# How to Output Results From Console to Email?

Tags: java, email, jdbc

I'm working on a java project that uses JDBC and Java Mail. I'm trying to send the output that I get from running my SQL statements to my email.

The problem is the msg.setText(), this is the method that inserts the text into the body of the email, is static. So, I can't put any of my methods that execute SQL statements in there as parameters because I can't make a static reference to the non-static method.

How do I send my output (the results in console) to an email address?

The expected output from the console is this:

```
ALLDONE: 0
COUNT(1): 0
IN_AC_IND: 0
Billing Count(1): 0
Signon: 0
```

So, in the body of the email that would be the entire message.

```
The code: 
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement; 
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class test {

    Connection conn; 

    public static void main (String[] args) {

    new test();
     email();

      } // end of main class

    public static void email(){
        final String SSL_FACTORY = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";
          // Get a Properties object
             Properties props = System.getProperties();
             props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
             props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", SSL_FACTORY);
             props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
             props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");
             props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "587");
             props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
             props.put("mail.debug", "true");
             props.put("mail.store.protocol", "pop3");
             props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
             final String username = "user";//
             final String password = "pass";
             try{
             Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, 
                                  new Authenticator(){
                                     protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                                     }});

           // -- Create a new message --
             Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

          // -- Set the FROM and TO fields --
             msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("email"));
             msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, 
                              InternetAddress.parse("email",false));
             msg.setSubject("Daily Activity Report");
             msg.setText("This is a test email ");
             msg.setSentDate(new Date());
             Transport.send(msg);
             System.out.println("Message sent.");

          }catch (MessagingException e){ System.out.println("Error: " + e);}
    }

    public test() {
        try
        {

            Class.forName("value");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("value", "value" , "value");
            execute();
            conn.close();

        }catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        }catch (SQLException ex)           {System.err.println(ex.getMessage());}
        }

    public void execute() {
        method();
        // someOtherMethod();
        method2();
        method3();
    }

    public void method(){
    String query = "SELECT ALLDONE FROM table";
    try{
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next())
        {
            String s = rs.getString ("ALLDONE");
            System.out.println("ALLDONE: " + s);
        }
    }catch (SQLException ex){
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Looking at your code, the [_msg.setText()_](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#setText(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method you mention is _NOT_ static.

Comment: Then why cannot do this: msg.setText(method()) ?

Comment: Because method is not defined.  Is it possible you defined it but left it out of your sample?

Comment: Yes, I left it out on purpose.

Comment: This is the error that I get: The method setText(String) in the type Part is not applicable for the arguments (void)

Comment: Ok...and what is method() returning?  If you want to pass it to setText, it needs to return a String.

Comment: I updated my question with that method. I hope that make it clearer.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45747968/how-do-i-send-the-results-of-my-program-to-email

Answer (score 0):

You need to have "method" return a String.  Here is a rewritten version of it:

```
public String method()
{
    String query = "SELECT ALLDONE FROM table";
    StringBuilder retval = new StringBuilder("");
    try
    {
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next())
        {
            String s = rs.getString("ALLDONE");
            retval.append(s + "\n");
            System.out.println("ALLDONE: " + s);
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException ex)
    {
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return retval.toString();
}
```

Note that along with printing the results to the console with System.out.println, we are adding them to a StringBuilder and then returning them as a String.

Comment: The program is able to run, but it sent a blank message to the email address. I also had to make connection static and the method() static as well. So, the changes are static Connection conn and public static String method().

Comment: That's great @Codes316, then perhaps you might upvote/accept my answer?

Comment: I'm sorry I meant it doesn't output the results from the method(), it just sends a blank message. I do appreciate your help!